# Vectorizing R loop for summation over vector section

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I want to sum over certain sections of a vector. The length of these sections are given by another vector, let's say `L = c(3,4)`. The vector whose elements should be summed up is `vec = c(3,4,2,6,5,8,1)` with `length(vec) = sum(L)`. As result I want to have a vector `sigma` which contains the sum over `sum(vec[1:L[1]])` and `sum(vec[(L[1]+1):L[2]])` or in this example `sum(vec[1:3])` and `sum(vec[4:7])`. In this small example the solution would be: `sigma[1] = 3+4+2 = 9` and `sigma[2] = 6+5+8+1 = 20`.
Please note that is just a small example and normally, `L` and `vec` have many more elements.

I want a fast solution for my problem. Probably reached through vectorization of my following loop:

```
L = c(3,4)       #length of sections
vec = c(3,4,2,6,5,8,1)  #creating vector for summation
L_cum = c(0,cumsum(L))  #creating vector for the length of sections with needed indices
sigma = 0
for(i in 1:length(L)){
 sigma[i] = sum(vec[(L_cum[i]+1):L_cum[i+1]])  #summation over vec[1:3] and vec[4:7]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should also work

```
diff(c(0,cumsum(vec)[cumsum(L)]))
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use

```
x <- rep(seq_along(L), L) # from akrun's comment
tapply(vec, x, sum)
 1  2 
 9 20
```

Comment: I don't know if that's called "vectorization" though

Comment: `each` works when there is only a single element in `L`

Comment: yes, but `each`  sound more natural in this context. Just my opinion though

Comment: It is a bit confusing.  `rep(1:3, each=3)`,works, but if you are using `rep(1:3, each=c(3,4,5))` it is still selecting the first one i.e 3

Comment: @Mamoun Benghezal Thanks for this solution! For `rep(seq_along(L), L)` one could also use `rep(1:length(L),times=L)`.